# File "<stdin>", line 1 error In QPython When Running def Function

Tags: syntax-error, stdin, qpython

I am using QPython on my Samsung Android V. I am studying from the book Think Python. The topic is about Adding New Functions such as: def print_lyrics:
print ("I am a lumberjack and I work all day."
Etc.
But when I attempt to run it I get an error saying, File "", line 1 error. 
1. I looked on Google but could not find the exact answer for this particular problem. I was about to look for a new app and delete QPython because I've been stuck for two days on this lesson. But I came here first. 
2. I tried different methods of doing this program function with no luck. 
3. I'm wondering if it just isn't available on the app, or am I failing to understand what I am doing wrong, or missing? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `def print_lyrics():`, you might want to read the basics http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/getting-started.html#functions

Comment: Thanks for link. I will read it. I actually figured it out by trial and error. I assume the Think Python book is outdated, so instead of entering  "def print_lyrics:"  only, as the book and so many websites say, you must type "def print_lyrics():".  It finally worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am editing my last answer:
I was mistaken when I read the text and the error was my fault.

Be sure and read thoroughly to avoid mistakes.